# How to Get a Color Value from App.xaml in a Page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have declared a color that I will be using a lot in my application, and I would like to be able to call that specific color within a page. This color will most likely be used in in XAML as well as code behind. In App.xaml I have

```
<Color x:Name="Blue" A="255" R="35" G="85" B="145"/>
```

But how would I call this in my Page's UI and code behind?

Actually to note, the above setting a color in App.xaml gives a debugging error on startup?

```
public App()
    {
        // Standard XAML initialization
        InitializeComponent(); //XamlParseException occurs here

        ...
    }
```

EDIT**

Update for SolidColorBrush not working

I have a Slider control and two ToggleSwitch controls declared in XAML, and I wish to change the Slider foreground in XAML and change the ToggleSwitch controls in code behind. Neither is working

App.xaml

```
<Color x:Key="ThemeColorBlue" A="255" R="35" G="85" B="145"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeBrushBlue" Color="{StaticResource ThemeColorBlue}"/>
```

and so when attempting to change the Slider control foreground in XAML I get no errors using

```
Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrushBlue}"
```

but when changing the ToggleSwitch foreground in code behind I get an error stating `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'`

```
this.ToggleSwitch.SwitchForeground = Application.Current.Resources["ThemeBrushBlue"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeBrushBlue" Color="{StaticResource ThemeColorBlue}"/>
```

Just repeat the color and it should work:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeBrushBlue" Color="#235591"/>
```

Comment: You must have added this as soon as I discovered the issue as well. I actually used `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeBrushBlue" Color="#FF235591"/>` because when setting the `Color` there was an Initialization error on text `255`. How would I use this in code behind though? Setting `Application.Current.Resources["ThemeBrushBlue"]` for ToggleSwitch is giving a type Object to Brush error.

Comment: you need to make a cast: `this.ToggleSwitch.SwitchForeground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["ThemeBrushBlue"]` but it is easier to do it in XAML `SwitchForeground ="{StaticResource ThemeBrushBlue}"`

Comment: Thanks, I believe I got it. The `ToggleSwitch` Foreground property in particular requires a cast of type `Brush`, not `SolidColorBrush`, which is where I was having issues.

Answer (score 23):

You would usually add the Color to `Application.Resources` with a `Key` instead of a `Name`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="Blue" A="255" R="35" G="85" B="145"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now you can access it in XAML as `StaticResource`, e.g.:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Blue}"/>
```

or in code like this:

```
var color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["Blue"];
```

Comment: I am having trouble implementing your solution. I added an edit to my original question above, maybe you could take a look and offer some advice?

Comment: The error message *Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'* says it all. The expression `Application.Current.Resources["ThemeBrushBlue"]` returns an `object`, but `ToggleSwitch.SwitchForeground` expects a `Brush`. You have to add an explicit cast (as I did in my answer): `ToggleSwitch.SwitchForeground = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["ThemeBrushBlue"];`