# Status Bar - Accent as Background Color

Tags: windows-10-universal

How to make that system accent color is background color of status bar in Windows 10 mobile app? I cannot figure out how to convert theme resource to background color in c#... Thank you!

Comment: I think that this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176909/how-to-get-a-color-value-from-app-xaml-in-a-page

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with Application.Current.Resources

### Example

**XAML**

```
    <Button x:Name="myButton" >AAA</Button>
```

**C#**

```
myButton.Background = (SolidColorBrush)  Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush"];
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

I hope that can help you

Comment: Will try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set it in code behind. Just use pure xaml:

```
<Button Background="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"/>
```